# How can i get the size of every db on my PostgreSQL server

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, npgsql

I need to get size of every table and every database on my PostgreSQL server in my c# console app.
I am using npgsql for server connection,and i`ve found script for table part

```
SELECT table_schema AS \"Database\", 
       SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 AS \"Size(MB)\" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
GROUP BY table_schema
```

but still i can`t switch databases. How can i connect to different databases on my server without knowing their names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of system information functions:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html

For database sizes:

```
select datname, pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname)) from pg_database ;
        datname         | pg_size_pretty 
------------------------+----------------
 my_test_db             | 7865 kB
 production             | 64 MB
 no_public_sch_template | 7857 kB
 test                   | 11 MB
 test_gz                | 9681 kB
 sch_test               | 7857 kB
 template0              | 7713 kB
 task_manager           | 9681 kB
 template1              | 7865 kB
 aquaculture            | 15 MB
 track_stocks           | 9425 kB
 track_stocks_test      | 9529 kB
 postgres               | 8273 kB
```

From pg_database you can get the database name(datname) for building a script to iterate over for the tables.